# Android post JSON to web service php and recieving JSON from service

Tags: php, android, json, post

Im trying to write a login service in the android by sending JSON to the web service i have in PHP after its processed in the web service JSON is returned back. My problem is sending JSON and then reading JSON in the android app. I have figured out basic posting in the app using ASyncTask but im not sure where to go from there, iv been doing a lot of searching on this and im kind of stumped right now. Any help is very appreciated!

Heres my .java file

```
package com.example.logintest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String APP_TAG = "demo";
public static EditText txtUserName;
public static EditText txtPassword;
Button btnLogin;
Button btnCancel;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtUserName=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtUname);
        txtPassword=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtPwd);
        btnLogin=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLogin=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new loginTask().execute();
        /*if((txtUserName.getText().toString()).equals(txtPassword.getText().toString())){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }*/

    }
   });   
   }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public static String postHttpResponse(URI absolute) {
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "Going to make a post request");
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String username = txtUserName.getText().toString();
        String password = txtPassword.getText().toString();
        try {
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost();
            post.setURI(absolute);
            List params = new ArrayList();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "login"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(post);
            if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                Log.d(APP_TAG, "HTTP POST succeeded");
                HttpEntity messageEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                InputStream is = messageEntity.getContent();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(APP_TAG, "HTTP POST status code is not 200");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(APP_TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "Done with HTTP posting");
        return response.toString();
    }

    class loginTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, String> { 

        //check if server is online
        protected String doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
            URI absolute = null;
            try {
                absolute = new URI("http://10.0.2.2/service/");
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return postHttpResponse(absolute);
        }

        //set status bar to offline if flag is false
        protected void onPostExecute(String xml) {
            //XMLfromString(xml);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have the actual response in Json Format available to you?

Comment: The JSON sent to the server will be processed through the database and depending on the information sent it will send back if it was a success or not and if not what error it was. Or do you mean you want the response that would be sent from the server?

Comment: For a great Java JSON library check out GSON. It's small, fast, and convenient to use: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: @Adonai : your code looking f9 then where u are getting problem? and how u are receiving json on server from android device ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K im not sending any JSON yet my problem is i cant quite figure out how to do so

Comment: @Adonai : in which parameter you are receiving json on server?

Comment: @Adonai : you want to send JSONObject or an JSONarray on server

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K i believe i want to send it as a JSONObject

Comment: @Adonai : plz check out my answer and let me known this is what exactly u r looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can send username and password as jsonobject as to server :

```
//your code here....
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("username", username);
json.put("password", password);

HttpPost post = new HttpPost();
post.setURI(absolute);
List params = new ArrayList();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "login"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("loginjson",json.toString()));
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(post);
//your code here....
```

on server side retrieve json object from loginjson queryString .

and for getting result back from server in json you will need to convert returned string from server to JsonObject ir JsonArray inside onPostExecute method of AsyncTask as :

```
protected void onPostExecute(String jsonstring) {
     // if server returning jsonobject 
       JSONObject jsonobj=new JSONObject(jsonstring);
          // get values from jsonobject

      // if server returning jsonArray
       JSONArray jsonarray=new JSONArray(jsonstring);
          // get values from JSONArray

}
```

Comment: Im looking at this trying to to get it to do something with my web service just so you know im working with this and not ignoring it

Comment: Alright iv got it to respond in JSON format successfully thanks for the help. I used my original send code but used you onPostExecute code

Comment: @Adonai : can u mark it as answer if this answer help u i solving current issue . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

well in our application we send json to our service using php. i do not send it in json format  directly instead i send it in string array format and let the php encode the json as for receiving back the data when i get the response from the server i just put it in string and then using JSONObject in java i convert it to json and parse the data.